# Could not able to push data to Elasticsearch using Logstash conf file Failed to execute action error is showing in Windows Powershell

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, logstash

I am following [a blog](https://medium.com/@svanschalkwyk/visualizing-sql-server-data-with-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-adbf71153d2f) to import data to Kibana when I followed those steps I am getting error in Logstash.

#### This is my configuration file:

```
    input { 
      file { 
       path => "C:/SalesJan2009/SalesJan2009.csv"  
       type => "csv"
       start_position => "beginning" 
       sincedb_path => "C:/SalesJan2009/sinceDb" }  
     } 
     filter { 
      csv { 
         separator => "," 
         columns => ["Transaction_date","Product","Price","Payment_Type","Name","City","State","Country","Account_Created","Last_Login","Latitude","Longitude"] 
         skip_empty_columns => "true"
         } 
         mutate { 
            convert => [ "Product" => "string" ]
            convert => [ "Price" => "float" ]
            convert => [ "Payment_Type" => "string" ]
            convert => [ "Name" => "string" ]
            convert => [ "City" => "string" ]
            convert => [ "State" => "string" ]
            convert => [ "Country" => "string" ]
            convert => [ "Longitude" => "float" ] 
            convert => [ "Latitude" => "float" ] 
         }
         date 
            {
                match => ["Transaction_date", "dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm:ss"]
                match => ["Account_Created", "dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm:ss"]
                match => ["Last_Login", "dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm:ss"]   
            }    
       }
        output {
            elasticsearch { hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
             index => "salestansactions2009"
        }   
      stdout {
        codec => dots
      }
         }
```

#### Error is:

```
PS A:\elk\logstash\logstash-7.4.2\bin> ./logstash -f C:\SalesJan2009\testdata.conf                                                                                      Thread.exclusive is deprecated, use Thread::Mutex
Sending Logstash logs to A:/elk/logstash/logstash-7.4.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2019-12-24T12:54:26,310][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2019-12-24T12:54:26,354][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.4.2"}
[2019-12-24T12:54:29,991][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, {, ,, ] at line 15, column 32 (byte 465) after filter { \r\n  csv { \r\n\t separator => \",\" \r\n     columns => [\"Transaction_date\",\"Product\",\"Price\",\"Payment_Type\",\"Name\",\"City\",\"State\",\"Country\",\"Account_Created\",\"Last_Login\",\"Latitude\",\"Longitude\"] \r\n\t skip_empty_columns => \"true\"\r\n\t } \r\n     mutate { \r\n       \tconvert => [ \"Product\" ", :backtrace=>["A:/elk/logstash/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:41:in `compile_imperative'", "A:/elk/logstash/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:49:in `compile_graph'", "A:/elk/logstash/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2584:in `map'", "A:/elk/logstash/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:10:in `compile_sources'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:153:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:47:in `initialize'", "A:/elk/logstash/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:26:in `initialize'", "A:/elk/logstash/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:36:in `execute'", "A:/elk/logstash/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:326:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2019-12-24T12:54:30,882][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2019-12-24T12:54:35,502][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the mutate-convert is wrong.
The error message says:

> "Expected one of #, {, ,, ] at line 15, column 32 (byte 465) after filter { \r\n  csv { \r\n\t separator => \",\" \r\n     columns => [\"Transaction_date\",\"Product\",\"Price\",\"Payment_Type\",\"Name\",\"City\",\"State\",\"Country\",\"Account_Created\",\"Last_Login\",\"Latitude\",\"Longitude\"] \r\n\t skip_empty_columns => \"true\"\r\n\t } \r\n     mutate { \r\n       \tconvert => [ \"Product\" ", ...

So the error is after convert => [ "Product"

Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert)

The value type is **hash**. So your usage of the square brackets ( [ ] ) is wrong. It should be:

```
input { 
  file { 
    path => "C:/SalesJan2009/SalesJan2009.csv"  
    type => "csv"
    start_position => "beginning" 
    sincedb_path => "C:/SalesJan2009/sinceDb" 
  }  
}

filter { 
  csv { 
    separator => "," 
    columns => ["Transaction_date","Product","Price","Payment_Type","Name","City","State","Country","Account_Created","Last_Login","Latitude","Longitude"] 
    skip_empty_columns => "true"
  }

  mutate { 
    convert => {
      "Product" => "string"
      "Price" => "float"
      "Payment_Type" => "string"
      "Name" => "string"
      "City" => "string"
      "State" => "string"
      "Country" => "string"
      "Longitude" => "float"
      "Latitude" => "float"
    }
  }

  date {
    match => ["Transaction_date", "dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm:ss"]
    match => ["Account_Created", "dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm:ss"]
    match => ["Last_Login", "dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm:ss"]   
  }    
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "salestansactions2009"
  }   
  stdout {
    codec => dots
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the solution mentioned by you but still i am facing an issue. following is arising.aLang::IllegalStateException", :message=>"Unable to configure plugins: Illegal pattern component: A", :backtrace=>["org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline.<init>(CompiledPipeline.java:100)", "org.logstash.execution.JavaBasePipelineExt.initialize(JavaBasePipelineExt.java:60)",

Comment: So whats the purpose of the date plugin? With the current configuration, you match three fields against the same date pattern and then take it as the value for the @timestamp field. Please remove two of the three match-lines and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this,

```
date {
    match => ["Transaction_date", "dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm:ss"]
    match => ["Account_Created", "dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm:ss"]
    match => ["Last_Login", "dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm:ss"]   
  }
```

Try to configure below code,

```
     date 
        {
            match => ["Transaction_date", "dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm:ss"]
      }
    date 
        {
            match => ["Account_Created", "dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm:ss"]
     }
     date 
        {
            match => ["Last_Login", "dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm:ss"]
     }
```

Comment: I have tried with this change as well though the error has been removed but data is not getting pushed to kibana. this error is occurring.A gauge metric of an unknown type (org.jruby.specialized.RubyArrayOneObject) has been create for key: cluster_uuids. This may result in invalid serialization.  It is recommended to log an issue to the responsible developer/development team.

Comment: @Vivek Kaushal This error occurres on all pipelines and can be ignored. Its a jruby warning. Please share the exact output with us!